# How can you get a random posistion around a known posistion in a 2d godot scene?

Tags: random, 2d, area, godot

I am making an game that is like asteroids and I want to place an asteroid around the player but not always in the same place and not to far or close.

this is my current code(planet is another asteroid with a rigid body sprite and collision shape):

```
func create_asteroid():
   var planet_instance = asteroid.instance()
   asteroid_instance.position = self.position
   get_tree().get_root().call_deferred("add_child", asteroid_instance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pick an angle at random:

```
var angle := rand_range(0, TAU)
```

Similarly, a distance:

```
var distance := rand_range(min_distance, max_distance)
```

And then figure out where that is from `self.position`. There is a `polar2cartesian` we can use for that:

```
asteroid_instance.position = self.position + polar2cartesian(distance, angle)
```

By the way, remember to call `randomize` at the start of the game, to seed the random number generator. *If you need more control over that (e.g. being able to input a seed) use the `RandomNumberGenerator` class.*

Comment: this works but it is the same every time I run it is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: @T-Rex `randomize`.